# Use settings page to change font color on mainpage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fonts

I'm trying to finish up an app and I have one small annoyance left. I can't use a  listpicker to change the font on a textbox on my mainpage from a "settings" page.  I've created a small test app so I wouldn't mess up my real app.  I hope someone can help.

What I have is 2 page app mainpage and text page. I have a textbox on the mainpage that I populated from the textpage from the text page I allow user to choose font style and color. I can change the style just not the color...some of the text boxes are just for testing. the txtMain textbox is the textbox that will have the font in it.

mainpage

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private IsolatedStorageSettings appsettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (appsettings.Contains("font"))
        {
            txtMain.Text = appsettings["font"].ToString();
        }

        if (appsettings.Contains("fontColor"))
        {
            string newColor = appsettings["fontColor"].ToString();
            txtColor.Text = newColor;
        }

        if (appsettings.Contains("colorSelect"))
        {
            string _colorSelect = appsettings["colorSelect"].ToString();
            txtColorSelect.Text = _colorSelect;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/text.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

text page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace test_font_color
{
    public partial class text : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private IsolatedStorageSettings appsettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        public SolidColorBrush colorSelection;

        public text()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //**********************for list box*************************
            List<colorChoices> source = new List<colorChoices>();
            source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Black.ToString(), pickedColor = "Black", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) });
            source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.White.ToString(), pickedColor = "White", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) });
            source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Red.ToString(), pickedColor = "Red", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
            this.lstColors.ItemsSource = source;
            this.lstColors.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(lstColors_SelectionChanged);
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (appsettings.Contains("font"))
            {
                appsettings.Remove("font");
                appsettings.Add("font", txtEnter.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                appsettings.Add("font", txtEnter.Text);
            }

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));              
        }

        public class colorChoices
        {
            //public Color pickedColorBlock
            public string pickedColorBlock
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string pickedColor
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public SolidColorBrush pickedSolidColorBrush
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        void lstColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            colorSelection = ((colorChoices)(lstColors.Items[lstColors.SelectedIndex])).pickedSolidColorBrush;
        }

        private void changeColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtEnter.Foreground = colorSelection;
            appsettings.Add("fontColor", txtEnter.Foreground);
            appsettings.Add("colorSelect", colorSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You want a settings page where the user can choose color and font. In the main page you want the text in txtMain to have the selected color and font (e.g. black and Arial)?

Comment: right. on the "settings" page the user will enter the text they want, choose the font and then choose the color of the font. then this is overlayed over a photo that they selected earlier which is displayed on the mainpage

Answer (score 0):

Define your custom SolidColorBrush in App.xaml code:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColor"
                         Color="Blue" />
```

Set it to your control using StaticResource

```
Foreground = {StaticResource FontColor};
```

In code it is accessible like this:

```
((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["FontColor"]).Color
```

Every color change will be automatically updated to every element, that uses this resource.